# Why org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto is empty in HADOOP SVN

Tags: eclipse, apache, hadoop

I am currently learning hadoop 2.5.
In order to modify some part of hdfs , I check out the HDFS project from [Hdfs resposity](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/tags/release-2.5.0/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs) , but after importing to eclipse, the complier cannot find the package "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto". This package is also empty in the SVN.

Any solutions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the build process described in the [BUILDING.txt](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.5.0/BUILDING.txt). The folder that you're missing are the protobuf files that are generated during the usual maven build.

Comment: Is that means I can ignore the errors before building?